# I have solved Balanced Brackets on Hackerrank and i encountered this error... can someone help me understand this?

Tags: c++, stack

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem
This is the question link

and here is my code :

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Complete the isBalanced function below.
string isBalanced(string s) {
    stack<char> st;
    for(int i=0;i<(int)s.size();i++)
    {
        switch(s[i])
        {
            case  '(' :
            case  '{' :
            case  '[' :
                st.push(s[i]);
                break;
            case ')' :
                **if(st.top()!='(' || st.empty())**
                {
                    return "NO";
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
            case '}' :
                **if(st.top()!='{' || st.empty())**
                {
                    return "NO";
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
            case ']' :
                **if(st.top()!='[' || st.empty())**
                {
                    return "NO";
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
        }
    }
    return st.empty() ? "YES" : "NO";
}
int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);

        string result = isBalanced(s);

        fout << result << "\n";
    }

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This code is not working. So I googled to find out the correct code.
See the correct code here:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

// Complete the isBalanced function below.
string isBalanced(string s) {
    stack<char> st;
    for(int i=0;i<(int)s.size();i++)
    {
        switch(s[i])
        {
            case  '(' :
            case  '{' :
            case  '[' :
                st.push(s[i]);
                break;
            case ')' :
                if(st.empty() || st.top()!='(')
                {
                    return "NO";
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
            case '}' :
                if(st.empty() || st.top()!='{')
                {
                    return "NO";
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
            case ']' :
                if(st.empty() || st.top()!='[')
                {
                    return "NO";
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
        }
    }
    return st.empty() ? "YES" : "NO";
}
int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    int t;
    cin >> t;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    for (int t_itr = 0; t_itr < t; t_itr++) {
        string s;
        getline(cin, s);

        string result = isBalanced(s);

        fout << result << "\n";
    }

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the correct code and see the only difference is the condition in the if bracket.
I am not understanding what I have done wrong?

Comment: Is `**if(st.top()!='[' || st.empty())**` to mark something significant or typo?

Comment: Bold text doesn't work in code, instead add a comment `// ...` after the line you want to mark.

Comment: The different order in the working code is essential. First you have to check whether there is anything on stack before accessing the top. The `||` is short-circuit - i.e. if the first argument evaluates to `true` the second is not checked. So, the first "saves" the possible invalid access to the second (in the 2nd snippet but not in your).

Answer (score 1):

The difference between

```
if(st.top()!='{' || st.empty())
```

and

```
if(st.empty() || st.top()!='{')
```

is the order of evaluation and short circuiting.

---

The first line will evaluate `st.top()!='{'` *first*. If `st` is empty at this point you get undefined behaviour that might manifest as crash.

The second line will *first* evaluate `st.empty()` and *only if this is false* it will go on to evaluate `st.top()!='{'`.

That's called short-circuit evaluation or just short-circuiting.

Answer (score 0):

`if(st.top()!='{' || st.empty())`

The compiler compiles this line down to two separate checks. As these two separate checks are probably two (or even more) instructions, one has to take precedence over the other.

In this case, `st.top() != '{'` is evaluated before `st.empty()`.